# Eloquent- chessboard in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to solve the 'chessboard' problem that's originally meant for js, in coffeescript; this is the question.

> Write a program that creates a string that represents an 8×8 grid, using newline characters to separate lines. At each position of the grid there is either a space or a “#” character. The characters should form a chess board. When you have a program that generates this pattern, define a variable size = 8 and change the program so that it works for any size, outputting a grid of the given width and height.

```
a = 8
b = 8
board = ""
x = 0 
y = 0


while y < a
 y = y + 1
 while x < b
  x = x + 1 
  if x % 2 == 0  
   board = board + "#"
  else
   board = board + " "

 print(board)
```

Everything seems to work fine, except the alterting of pattern by row. It currently looks like this:

```
" # # # #"
" # # # #"
" # # # #"
" # # # #"
" # # # #"
" # # # #"
" # # # #"
" # # # #"
```

But I want it to look like this.

```
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Comment: `if (x + (y % 2)) % 2` <- the condition you need

Comment: @JonasW. Doesn't seem to work still, even with this edit.

Answer (score 0):

The updated condition from @Jonas W. was correct, but you also need to reset the `x` and `board` variable in your loop:

```
a = 8
b = 8
board = ""
x = 0 
y = 0


while y < a
 y = y + 1
 x = 0
 board = ""
 while x < b
  x = x + 1 
  if (x + (y % 2)) % 2 == 1
   board = board + "#"
  else
   board = board + " "
 print(board)
```

but even here there's some inconsistencies with your briefing - the `board` variable is infact just a row. Rather than reseting it, you probably want to append a newline ("\n") character after every row is created. But that would also mean you have to de-indent your print line another level as right now it prints it out after every row is generated.

I'd suggest taking a look into [Coffeescript comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) rather than using those while loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = ""
for (let i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        a += "#"
    } else (a += " ")
    if (i % 8 == 0) {
        if ((i / 8) % 2 == 0) {
            a += "\n";
        }
        else {
            a += "\n"
            a += " "
        }
    }
}
console.log(a)
```